# ASP.Net MVC 3 Configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, configurationmanager

i want to ask about ASP.Net Configuration. i have a project that use ASP.Net MVC3. and i use membership in my project. in my database server, there's 2 database for my project.

1. aspnetdb, contains aspnet_membership, aspnet_user, aspnet_roles, etc (i use asp.net Configuration)
2. mydatabase, its for my project database.

now my boss told me that he want to host my project in public and told me to use only one database. so i have to move aspnetdb to mydatabase. how can i do it without making new table in mydatabase ?

thanks

Comment: You just need to move the asp_net tables into mydatabase. Obviously you have to create these tables in mydatabase, unless you already have your own user schema?

Comment: thanks thecodeking for reply. but if i host my project, can i use those table ? i mean that i still use two database ( because there's a lot to do if i making new table in mydatabase).

Comment: What's the question? You can use two databases if your hosting provider allows it, or you can move those existing tables into the one database, what's a lot of work?

Comment: i mean if i move my aspnetdb to mydatabase, is there any change in my edmx file ?

Comment: The only change is the connection string, and asp.net sql membership providers don't use the entity framework anyway.

Comment: thanks TheCodeKing, you're helping me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the ASP.NET membership provider uses a built-in connectionString named `LocalSqlServer` which is something like this:

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and when you use the `Membership` for first time (or when you use the web configuration manager tool), the `aspnetdb.mdf` will be created automatically. For first step, you can remove this `connectionString` from `web.config` by `clear` command:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <!-- your other connectionStrings -->
  </connectionStrings>
```

and also, you must change the `connectionString` for `membershipProvider` (and also `roleProvider` if you use it) in `web.config` file:

```
<membership userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
         connectionStringName="YourSpecifiedConnectionString" // your connectionString here
         name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="500" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="YourSpecifiedConnectionString" // your connectionString here
         name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"  
         applicationName="/" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

For configure the database to use **ASP.NET** built-in membership provider, you can use regsql tool
which can be founded here:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\(version that you are using. mine is v4.0.30319)\
```

In this folder, find the `aspnet_regsql.exe` file and run it. A helpful wizard will be shown and 
help you step by step to configure new database. And about your final issue: You haven't to apply any change 
to your `edmx` file! The EF works with tables you supplied to it, and `membershipProvider` do its job with 
tables that **ASP.NET** supplied to it! Well done, Good job!

Comment: You are welcome (^_^) and thank you to accept. If this answer is helpful, vote it up please. Thank you again. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add those tables to your own database. It's quite easy. Just use the `aspnet_regsql` tool to export the database schema to a SQL file and run that file in your own database.

Instruction:
http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Install-ASPNET-Membership-Provider-on-a-Shared-Hosting-Company.aspx